# Run ArUco example using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, aruco

I am new to Cmake and to build projects using it. I have not used this tool before and hence have less knowledge on how it works.
I am trying to get the examples of  the ArUco library run. But the README provided by the ArUco library suggests to use the Cmake to run them. I have Windows 8.1 and Visual studio 2013 and I have also downloaded and installed the Cmake3.4.0 . 
After installing it I searched for examples or tutorials on Cmake, and found a few [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYmgbqGfv-8) that showed how to compile programs using cmake. But while followed the same steps I got errors. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2lIE.png) is as shown

I went through different questions posted in the forum but didn't find an answer. I am not sure I need to set Environment variables and paths. Some suggestions on this would be really helpful.
Thank you very much for the help.

Error:

The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findaruco.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "aruco", but
  CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "aruco" with any of
  the following names:

```
arucoConfig.cmake<br/>
aruco-config.cmake<br/>
```

Add the installation prefix of "aruco" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "aruco_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "aruco"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/../aruco_testproject/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: First of all you should mention what you did in particular:

 - Which commands did you enter
 - In which folder did you execute them

and even more important provide your error messages in your SO post and not as image attachement. Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. So I have the ArUco library downloaded from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/ . They are saved in my E drive. In Cmake I browse the location for this file and create a build location inside the same path. Error is as shown in the screenshot. I cannot attach pictures directly, I will try to add the full error on the question

Comment: You really need to start marking questions as answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its pretty clear whats goin wrong. CMake cant find certain packages.

### Quick and dirty solution

One solution is to do what the error message suggests:

Go into the specific `CMakeLists.txt` file and set the `aruco_Dir` variable like that

```
set( auruco_Dir /PATH/TO/ARUCO/WHERE/AURUCOCONFIG.CMAKE/IS/LOCATED/AS/WELL )
```

### The true way

A better approach is to provide the `Findaruco.cmake` module in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. This is called module because it integrates with CMake's `find_package` mechanism (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html, Last accessed at 11.12.2015) and provides the **central** information about where `aruco` can be found in your file system. (`Aruco` is just exemplary here. Same goes for any other module)

#### What is this good for, why do I need `find_package`and those *modules*?

Answer is simple. You have only one central place to manage and not many. Imagine the location of your pacjage changes. Do you want to fix every single `CMakeLists.txt` file referencing this package?
Its like basic programming paradigms

- > Dont repeat yourself
- > Dont hardcode anything

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @MarkusAtCvlabDotDe . I would like to do it the true way. From where can i get the Findaruco.cmake and how do I provide it to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ? Would be nice if you could give me some details on it.

Comment: I suggest you google such things on your own. https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for

Comment: Thank you @MarkusAtCvlabDotDe

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark the question as anwsered in case your problem has been solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Mac, hope Windows users find this useful too.

Most probably you did't install aruco. Go to the aruco source folder that you dowloaded (ie ~/Downloads/aruco-2.0.14) and run following commands

  `cmake .
  make
  make install`

Then you will be able to build aruco_testproject

  `cmake .
  make`

Hope this helps